# Google Map is shown only on top left corner of the map div

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

Using [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map) I tried to embed google map inside Razor web page.

```
<script>
    function initialize() {           
        var lat = 45.430817;
        var lon = 12.331516;

        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var mapOptions = {                
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
        var center = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(center); 
    });
</script>
```

But final result looks like this

[image]

Comment: The  `map-canvas` is visibile at startup or is hidden? The height and width of `map-canvas` and his parents were properly assigned or there are elements without dimensions?

Comment: it's visible but it's under tab content. This map is shown after tab is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

It has already happened to me. In this case you need to add a resize right after the tab click. some things like:

```
<div id='init_tab' class='tab_item' onclick="google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');">
```

Comment: I'm sorry but for the correct view of a map shown after a tab  click is mandatory to do a `map resize`,   otherwise you must initialize your map in a function and call the function with the onClick event.